# TYPO3 Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage::getBeginn()

Tags: typo3, repository

I have TYPO3 extension with some custom function in repository. I have in this model 1:n relation (events is parent and dates are child elements).

I tried to get the beginning date of child elements with

```
foreach($events as $key => $value) {
        echo $value->getDates()->getBeginn();
    }
```

But I get error "Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage::getBeginn()". How can I initalize the ObjectStorage in repository?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `getBeginn` is a function in the `Date` model and each `Event` object can have multiple `Date` objects attached to it.

Assuming this is correct, the `getDates` function in an `Event` object will return a collection of `Date` objects, not just one. In TYPO3 this is done using an `ObjectStorage`. You can see (and use) this as an array which (in this case) contains `Date` objects.

So for example you can do:

```
foreach($events as $event) {
    foreach ($event->getDates() as $date) {
        echo date->getBeginn();
    }
}
```